# How to add all (label, button, subview) in scrollview?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I designed on the main view with the auto layout but I forget to add scrollView.

am I need to add scrollview programmatically or redesign my view?

Here is my code

```
var scrollView: UIScrollView!

//viewDid load        
    let screensize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
    let screenWidth = screensize.width
    let screenHeight = screensize.height
    scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight))

    for view in view.subviews{

        let constraint = 

        scrollView.addSubview(view)
    }
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)
```

Comment: Looks like you don't have a single parent view for all your subviews. The straightforward solution would be to remove the top constraint of the topmost subview and attach ScrollView's top constraint (same goes for the bottom-most view (attach the bottom constraint to the bottom)). Left and right constraints need to be set for all. I would recommend putting all the subviews in a single view (preferably in storyboard), then you just have one subview to deal with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite hard to say what kind of view hierarchy do you have in your view controller and what kind of relationship they have but this may help you in some form or shape.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let s = UIScrollView()
        s.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(s)
        s.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        s.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        s.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        s.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        return s
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let subviews = view.subviews

        // remove all subviews from main view
        view.subviews.forEach {
            $0.removeFromSuperview()
        }

        // create vertical stackview, this will help to write less constraints on each subview
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.alignment = .fill
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.distribution = .fill

        // all all subviews in stackview
        subviews.forEach {
            stackView.addArrangedSubview($0)
        }

        // add stackview in main view
        scrollView.addSubview(stackView)
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

This is my view controller on the storyboard. After view controller appears on screen this two views will be wrapped inside scrollview.
[image]